# remove margin from second div?

Tags: jquery, css

i have one single class for margin and i am using this class to two different div but i want to margin 0 in second div, i dont want to change html because if i do that i will have work on many pages so i want to do that either jquery or css. i tried it to do that with child selector but it wont work for me.

```
<style>
.margn { margin-top:20px;}

</style>



<body>
<div class="margn">hii</div>

<div id="call" class="margn">bye</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use jQuery here as per your tag in the question

just right the below code. Remember you include jquery file.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$("#call").css("margin-top", "0 !important"); // or 
$("#call").css("margin-top", "0");     

});
```

**EDIT :** 
Also if you want to use only CSS you can refer the answer by @sandeep below.
remember CSS works sepquentially so write your css in proper sequence.

in CSS

```
.margn{margin-top:20px;} /* after this line write style for your div having id. */
#call {margin:0;}
```

Comment: `!important` wouldn't be necessary because css rules are applied sequentially if you apply the inline style after the class has been applied the inline will take effect over the class styles http://jsfiddle.net/LhjMz/2/

Comment: yes it was just to keep a safe idea. but @3nigma your code will not work if i need to give this style to some other div also. coz it is specific to second div only. there may be scenario where div may increase or the second div moves to third place at that time i need to change the code as well.

Comment: since the question is tagged for jQuery and css.

Comment: It's a basic rule of Front End development always give first preference to CSS & if the desire result is not achieved by CSS then use JS

Answer (score 4):

for the markup you have given try

```
$("div:eq(1)").removeClass('margn');
```

or if you want to remove margn from divs that have class margn

```
$(".margn:eq(1)").removeClass("margn");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LhjMz/)

Comment: there was a jquery tag added to the question so i provided the jquery solution

Comment: It's a basic rule of Front End development always give first preference to CSS & if the desire result is not achieved by CSS then use JS

Answer (score 2):

@amit i know you accept answer but you can achieve this with pure css. write like this:

```
.margn { margin-top:20px;}
#call{margin:0}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7dCcs/2/

**OR**

```
#call.margn{margin:0}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7dCcs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just do in your stylesheet,

```
#call{
  margin: 0;
}
```

id always overrides class styles.